# How to check for NULL(empty/0) strings if I don't have access to the string variables

Tags: c++

Edit: Sorry if I did not specify, I can **NOT** change these given structs and classes. So I can not make get/set functions for the fields in the Student struct and Grade class.

This is an assignment of two parts, part 1 was relatively easy and has a struct like so:

**Part1** (Student.h) Can NOT be changed

```
const unsigned int MAX_GRADES= 5;

struct Student
{
    char* studentText;
    unsigned int numSubjects;
    Grade grades[MAX_ANSWERS];
    Student():studentText(0){};
    ~Student();
};
```

Then in part 2 that has changed to:

**Part2** (Student.h) Can NOT be changed

```
struct Student
    {
            static const unsigned int MAX_GRADES = 5;
            Student():studentText(0){;}
            Student(char*,unsigned int,Grade*);
            Student(Student&);
            ~Student();
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Student&);
    private:
        char* studentText;
        unsigned int numSubjects;
        Grade grades[MAX_GRADES];
    };
```

Grade is a class with also private string:

**Part2** (Grade.h) Can NOT be changed

```
 class Grade
    {
        char* subject;
        bool pass;
    public: 
        Grade():subject(0){;}
        Grade(char*,bool);
        Grade(Grade&);
        ~Grade();
        Grade& operator=(Grade&);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Grade&);
    };
```

The variable *studentText* that I used to use to check if a Student is empty inside students[] by using:

```
if(students[j]->studentText==0)
```

Has now become private and I can not reach it from my main. Can anyone point me to the right direction.

Can I use the overloaded << to somehow get studentText and test if it is 0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a public function in student that returns whether it has text or not ...

Comment: I would suggest not _wanting_ to check "if a student is empty". You should design your classes so that they are valid for their entire lifetime. What's an empty student? That doesn't sound like a valid state of a student. You can either have an array of optional<Student> or unique_ptr<Student> to get the same effect though.

Comment: You're writing C++ now. Use `std::string`, not `char*`. Use `std::vector`, not raw arrays. Also with `std::string` implementing the overloaded `<<` operator becomes trivial as you don't need to check for null.

Comment: @Dave: From what I remember, being an 'empty student' is a fairly common state.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the struct and class can not be changed as per the assignment guidelines. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I agree with the comments about using std::string, and not determining whether the student is empty by its text field.

However, if you insist on getting the text field which is private from `Student` you can add a public method for that, which will also return the string as `const char*`.
This will be safe enough to do for your `Student` struct.

```
const char* getStudentText() const {
    return studentText;
}
```

Then outside the class you could use it in your if statement as follows:

```
if (students[j]->getStudentText() == NULL) ...
```

Another thing you could do which is a little more elegant (just a little) is ask the student if it is empty (using a method) - this way the student holds the logic that says that being empty means that the textual field is empty (slightly better encapsulation).

you could add this method to your `Student` struct:

```
bool isEmpty() const {
    return studentText == NULL;
}
```

And then ask outside the class:

```
if (students[j]->isEmpty()) ...
```

**Edit: after the op's comment**

That's really unfortunate that you can't edit the struct / class and still want to know if the private string is empty. It's kinda like coding with your hands behind your back.

Anyhow, there is a solution for your situation (however ugly it may be):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << students[j];
std::string s = oss.str();

if (s.empty()) ...
```

You'll need to `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the struct and class can not be changed as per the assignment guidelines. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Added a way to check the string without changing the class. Not pretty, but given your constraints...

Comment: Thanks, maybe you can help me again. I have two arrays. One is of fixed size (MAX_GRADES which is 5) and one in my main depends on how many grades I want to enter(lets say 3). Now, if you see my struct above it has 'Student(char*,unsigned int,**Grade***);' so I'm passing the not-fixed size array into this overloaded constructor, how can I copy the content of the small array into the big one, every time I use a for loop it crashes because the array has two empty 'slots'. The code you gave me also crashes when oss reads in an empty 'slot' in the array.

Comment: First of all about the crash, it's not crashing on the oss, it's crashing on an attempt to use unallocated memory in your array (inferring from you writing 'empty slot') - you need to know your array's boundaries. Same goes for your array copy problem. you need to copy the correct number of elements in your case, 3. Usually in such cases it is common to differentiate logical array size from physical size. btw, please accept (tick) the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you need to access a private variable, here's what you do. This is common and good practice, take my word for it. Do this any time you need to access a private:

Put this stuff in main.cpp after you #include "Student.h":

```
template<typename T>
struct invisible
{
    static typename T::type value;
};

template<typename T>
typename T::type invisible<T>::value;

template<typename T, typename T::type P>
class construct_invisible
{
    construct_invisible(){ invisible<T>::value = P; }
    static const construct_invisible instance;
};

template<typename T, typename T::type P>
const construct_invisible<T, P> construct_invisible<T, P>::instance;

struct Student_studentText{ typedef char* Student::*type; };
template class construct_invisible<Student_studentText, &Student::studentText>;
```

Your condition would look like this:

```
if(students[j]->*invisible<Student_studentText>::value == 0)
```

No need to change Student.h at all. I'm 99% sure this is what your teacher is expecting.

Comment: Thanks, but we're not doing templates yet. Would be to obvious if you know what I mean. But I will try this for a reference for later assignments. Thanks a lot!